# percentage on legend scale in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to display percentage instead of values in the legend text. 
I tried using `formats.percentage` but it is not giving the desired result, in fact, there is no display of text.

```js
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });

legend.enter().append("g").attr("class", "legend");

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
    .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

legend.append("text")
    .attr("class", "mono")
    // .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })   -- this was original
    // replaced with below piece
    .text(function(d) {
        var r = colors.invertExtent(d);
        return formats.percent(r[0]);
    }
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
    .attr("y", height + gridSize);

legend.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use d3 formatting tools : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting

To use it you do the following :

```
d3.format(' insert format parameter here ')(insert value here);
```

instead of formats.percent(r[0]);

In your case it would be :

```
.text(d3.format('%')(r[0]));
```

Be aware though that it's not just adding a '%' after your value, it "multiply by 100 and suffix with "%"" as stated in the doc.

Below is an example of how to use it with dummy numbers :

```js
var r = [ 0.4, 80]; //Whatever values you have in r

var s = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 500);

s.append('text')
  .text( d3.format('%')(r[0]) ) //Thats where you apply the format : 0.4 -> 40%
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 20);

s.append('text')
  .text( d3.format('%')(r[1]) )
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 40);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: perfect. I got the output in percentage form. Thanks